# Mousedown or touchstart called?

Tags: javascript, touchscreen

There's one thing that disturbs me: suppose, I have a laptop with mouse and touch display. What event will be called when I touch some object in a browser on a screen? Mousedown or touchstart?
And another situation: what event will be called when I use a tablet with usb-mouse and make mouse-click at the browser?

Hope you can give me the answer.

Comment: Why not write some code and try it to determine what happens?

Comment: @JonathanM, because I don't have such devices

Comment: Then write some code in a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) that will give the feedback you're wanting. Post it here and ask others to use their touch screens and USB mice. Ask them to let you know the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked it and here are results:

- Android Chrome caused 'touchstart'
- Android FF caused 'touchstart'
- Android browser (4.0.*) caused 'touchstart' and then 'mousedown'
- Android Opera caused both of them
- Laptop with Windows 8 and FF and touch display caused 'mousedown' when using touch
- The same laptop with Chrome caused both of events

A bit fanny. You can check it by yourself: jsfiddle.net/z5cygsb4/2/